# Стрелочные функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

**Задание:** C помощью стрелочных функций получить из массива положительные числа и вычислить квадрат этих чисел.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";

  const squaredIntegers = arr.filter((number) => number > 0).map((number) => number * number)


return squaredIntegers;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

В чем ошибка? Возможно ли такая запись функций через точку?

**Уточнение: Код изначально выглядит так**

```html
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  // change code below this line
  const squaredIntegers = arr;
  // change code above this line
  return squaredIntegers;
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

вывод ответа должен быть: squaredIntegers should be [16, 1764, 36].

Код добавлял только между линиями. Но пока ответ не принимет
[image: code]

Comment: `//    };` вкралась лишняя скобка

Comment: исправлено, но пока код не рабочий

Comment: лишняя скобка  перед `return squaredIntegers;`

Comment: Вам надо проверять еще на то, что числа - целые.

Comment: `number > 0 && number % 1 == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];

const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";

  const squaredIntegers = arr.filter((number) => number > 0 && number % 1 == 0).map((number) => number * number)
  return squaredIntegers;
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

*Упражнение.* Получение суммы квадратов целых положительных элементов.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
var result = realNumberArray.reduce( 
  (result, item) => result + ((item > 0 && item % 1 == 0)? item*item : 0), 
0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Все отлично. Спасибо!